# If all homomorphisms $f:G→H$ are trivial or injective, then G is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a nontrivial group. Show that $G$ is simple if and only if, for every group $H$ and homomorphism $f:G→H$, either $f$ is trivial or $f$ is injective.

So I have already proved that if $f$ is trivial, then given any normal subgroup $G'$ of $G$, $G'$={1}. But I have problem proving that if $f$ is injective, then given any normal subgroup $G'$ of G, $G'=G$. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: I would prove both sides contrapositively myself. If $G$ is not simple, there exists $N$ such that $\{1\}\triangleleft N\triangleleft G$. Can you show a homomorphism from $G$ to $G/N$? what properties would it have. 

For the other direction if there exists a homomorphism $f:G\to H$ that is non-trivial non-injective, then what can we say about its kernel?

Comment: Your title was not the same as your question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Take $H=G/N$ and the quotient homomorphism $f: G \to G/N$.

*Solution:*

If $f$ is trivial, then $N=G$.

If $f$ is injective, then $N=\ker f=1$.

Therefore, the only normal subgroups of $G$ are $1$ and $G$, and so $G$ is simple.

Comment: Well, does this mean that if $f$ is injective, then the normal subgroup of $G$ is {1}?